# How to turn speaker ON making call on android Jellybean

Tags: android, call, android-4.2-jelly-bean

What I'm trying to do is to make call from my app and turn on speaker in this call.

Everything was okay on android 4.0, I've just set **audiomanager.setSpeakerphoneOn(true)** before starting call intent.

But on android 4.1 PhoneUtils checkin speaker state before call and turn it off(logcat):

```
D/PhoneUtils( 1029): about to activate speaker
D/PhoneUtils( 1029): activateSpeakerIfDocked()...
I/PhoneUtils( 1029): Forcing speaker off when initiating a new outgoing call...
```

I've also tried to listen call state using : mTelephonyManager.listen(receiver, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
After this receiver will catch 3 states:

- IDLE(don't interesting for mee)
- CALL_STATE_RINGING(also don't interesting because I need work with outgoing calls)
- CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK(i though this one will help)

But last "event" was also send before PhoneUtils check speaker state(logcat):

```
11:43:48.089 D/KeyguardViewMediator( 665): keyguard receiver action : android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE
11:43:48.089 D/KeyguardViewMediator( 665): keyguard receiver TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE : OFFHOOK
11:43:48.099 D/PhoneUtils( 977): setAudioMode()...OFFHOOK
11:43:48.099 D/MyPhoneStateListener:main( 2590): catching call state CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK
11:43:48.099 D/MyPhoneStateListener:main( 2590): turning phone speaker on
...
11:43:48.119 D/PhoneUtils( 977): about to activate speaker
11:43:48.119 I/PhoneUtils( 977): Forcing speaker off when initiating a new outgoing call...
```

If somebody faced with same problem or have a solutuion?

Thanks!

Comment: On which phone is this? In vanilla Android speakermode should only be turned off for incoming calls, not for outgoing calls.

Comment: @Michael I'm trying to do it on galaxy nexus.

Comment: Could you please give more info, why it should turn off only for incoming calls?
Thanks!

Comment: Because the code in question contains a check for whether the call is an incoming call. At least when I look at the code at the Codeaurora Forum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had this problem this week..

Reading the jelly bean code source, i've found this code

```
// This is not an error but might cause users' confusion. Add log just in case.
Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Forcing speaker off when initiating a new outgoing call...");    
PhoneUtils.turnOnSpeaker(app, false, true);
```

So that's it, in version 4.1 android forces speaker off in incoming and outgoing calls.
My solution is turn on the speaker in my call state broadcast receiver, after start to make a call

Comment: Thanks for answer!
I've tried to use broascast reciever too, but I recieved this intent before call:
`13:56:16.565 D/VoiceDial:main( 2554): recieve call event<--- onRecieve(Intent.ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL)`

`13:56:16.875 D/PhoneUtils( 1017): about to activate speaker`

Comment: Molokoka you get that because the "intent" of that intent is to give you a chance to redirect a call. I don't know how to solve it, but that's why you get it before the call.